# Combine two queries in a while loop including group by

Tags: php, mysql

How can I combine these two queries? What the end-result should look like you can see on the bottom. Examples and code are minimized.

```
SELECT t1.name, plot 
FROM TableTimes t2, TableInfo t1 
WHERE week = 201825 AND t2.idFI = t1.id AND deleteSZ = false 
GROUP BY idFI 
ORDER BY TimeSZ
```

giving me:

```
+--------+-------+
| name   | plot  |
+--------+-------+
| name11 | abc   |
+--------+-------+
| name22 | xyz   |
```

Another query giving me the times which belong to the names from query1 (name11, name22...)

```
SELECT t2.DateSZ, TimeSZ, t1.name 
FROM TableTimes t2, TableInfo t1 
WHERE week = 201825 AND t2.idFI = t1.id AND deleteSZ = false 
ORDER BY DateSZ, TimeSZ
```

giving me:

```
+------------+--------+--------+
| DateSZ     | TimeSZ | name   |
+------------+--------+--------+
| 2018-06-21 | 08:00  | name11 |
+------------+--------+--------+
| 2018-06-22 | 09:00  | name11 |
+------------+--------+--------+
| 2018-06-22 | 20:00  | name22 |
+------------+--------+--------+
| 2018-06-24 | 04:00  | name11 |
```

At the moment I'm only displaying query1 in a whileloop div:

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{?>
<ul>
    Some text ......
<li><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['name']);?>" /><</li>
    Some more text ......
<li><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['plot']);?>" /><</li>

<li>
    <table class="">
        <thead></thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>DateSZ</th>
              <th>TimeSZ</th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
    </table>
</li>
</ul>

<?php }?>
```

But I want to add query2. How can I output the table on the intended place with the associated dateSZ and TimeSZ only?

The output should look something like:

```
Some text ...... name11 
some more text ...... abc
+------------+--------+
| DateSZ     | TimeSZ |
+------------+--------+
| 2018-06-21 | 08:00  |
+------------+--------+
| 2018-06-22 | 09:00  |
+------------+--------+
| 2018-06-24 | 04:00  |

Some text ...... name22 
some more text ...... xyz
+------------+--------+
| DateSZ     | TimeSZ |
+------------+--------+
| 2018-06-22 | 20:00  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestions from DataVader I found a working solution. It is of course not the best but as I need this function rarely it does the job.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT `name`, plot, idFI FROM TableTimes INNER JOIN TableInfo ON TableInfo.id = TableTimes WHERE week = 201825 AND deleteSZ = false GROUP BY idFI ORDER BY TimeSZ";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ( mysqli_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
?>
<ul>
    Some text ......
<li><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['name']);?></li>
    Some more text ......
<li><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['plot']);?></li>

<li>

<table class="">

<?php
$query1 = "SELECT idFI, TableInfo.`name`, plot, TableTimes.DateSZ, TimeSZ FROM TableTimes INNER JOIN TableInfo ON TableInfo.id = TableTimes.idFI WHERE week = 201825 AND deleteSZ = false AND TableTimes.idFI = '".$row['idFI']."' ORDER BY DateSZ, TimeSZ";
$res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1) or die ( mysqli_error());
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1))
{
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row1['DateSZ']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row1['TimeSZ']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?> 
</table></li>
</ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you join them properly without grouping them, so you get it denormalized. Then you use one of many php-functions to do what you desire (array_walk(), array_map()).

This answer probably isn't what you wished for, so my question to you:
Do you have troubles creating the query or doing it in PHP? Do you need code examples or can you figure it out by yourself from here on?

From what I can see, you probably just started both by using a tutorial from 2002 or some legacy project. You should consider switching from mysqli to PDO and from such queries to real joins.

edit:
First of you do the SQL:

```
SELECT
            idFI,
            TableInfo.`name`,
            plot,
            TableTimes.DateSZ,
            TimeSZ,
FROM        TableTimes
INNER JOIN  TableInfo
    ON      TableInfo.id = TableTimes.idFI
WHERE       week = 201825
            AND deleteSZ = false 
ORDER BY    DateSZ,
            TimeSZ;
```

Then you can loop over it with something like:

```
$myArr = [];

//restructure the array
array_walk(
    $result,
    function($row) use ($myArr){
        if(!isset($myArr[$row['idFI'])){
            $myArr[$row['idFI']] = [];
        }
        $myArr[$row['idFI']][] = [
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'plot' => $row['plot'],
            'DateSZ' => $row['DateSZ'],
            'TimeSZ' => $row['TimeSZ']
        ];
    }
);

array_walk(
    $myArr,
    function($parent){
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>'.htmlspecialchars($parent[0]['name']).'</li>';
        //some more text
        echo '<li>'.htmlspecialchars($parent[0]['name']).'</li>';
        echo '<li>
            <table class=''>
                <thead/>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>DateSZ</th>
                        <th>TimeSZ</th>
                    </tr>';
        array_walk(
            $parent,
            function($child){
                echo '<tr>
                        <td>'.$child['DateSZ'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$child['TimeSZ'].'</td>
                    </tr>';
            }
        );

        echo     '</tbody>
                </table>
            </li>
        </ul>';
    }
);
```

May not work exactly like that because I typed it in an editor real quick but when using an IDE, the errors should be easy to fix.

Also, try switching from mysqli to PDO and really avoid writing queries like "FROM tableA A, tableB B WHERE a.id1 = b.id2;" and start using joins.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am afraid I don't exactly understand how to solve it your way. Could you help me? Oh and yes, I startet not a long time ago.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found three minor syntax errors: delete the comma in the query after TimeSZ, change <table class=''> to <table class=""> and I had to add a ] on line if(!isset($myArr[$row['idFI']])){. However I really don't get your code to work. The query works finde, and btw I changed all my queries to that, thanks for that, but It just do not want to output anything. Did I miss something?